# Automatically replace 'A' by 'B', 'B' by 'A', 'C' by 'D', etc... in a list?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was any way to automatically replace certain elements in a list by other ones, without using an if..else statement for each element ?
Something like this :

```py
# before :
aL = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# after :
aL = ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: What happens with `z`?

Comment: 'z' becomes 'a'.

Comment: considering x is your list, this will do the job                                                              
         [chr(  97+ (((ord(i)+1)%97)%26)  ) for i in x]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it,

```
aL = ['a', 'b', 'c','z']
expected = []
for ch in aL:
    if ch == 'z':
        expected.append(chr(ord(ch)-25))
    else:
        expected.append(chr(ord(ch) + 1))
print(expected)
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/LVY19713